# MongoDB: How to only pull document with exact search term

Tags: mongodb

I'm sure this is somewhere on here but I can't seem to find it. I'm trying to pull a document from a large file that only matches an exact term in a field, as opposed to anything with those letters in it.

More precisely, I'm trying to use .find({"name":"Eli"}) to pull the documents with that name, but my search is pulling every name with those letters (such as elizabeth or ophelia)

Comment: .find({"name":"Eli"}) will give you only documents with exact name "Eli"

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/fSX8PYicqOn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regular expression match to make sure you do not return names that share the same character formation.

Something like this:

```
const name = "Eli"
const query = new RegExp(`^${name}$`)
const user = await Collection.find({ name: { $regex: query } })
```

I am using 2 key operators from RegEx here: `^` and `$`

Putting `^` in front of a regular expression will match all strings that start with the pattern given.

Putting `$` at the end of a regular expression will match all strings that end with the pattern given.

So essentially you are asking mongoose to find the record where the `name` both begins and ends with `Eli`.  This will prevent Elizabeth from showing up in your result, but won't filter out other Eli's.